# Combination of Wiener Processes

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

If $W_s$ and $W_t$ are wiener processes, we have that the probability that $W_s$ and $W_t$ attain maximum is (I am concluding this from "running maximum", but I am not sure) $$P(W_s<a)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^a e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}dx$$ and $$P(W_t<a)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^a e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}dx$$
I am trying to compute the probability that $$P(\sqrt{(|W_s|^2+|W_t|^2)}<r)$$

More precisely, I would appreciate hints for computing the probability that a 2-dimensional wiener process lies inside the disc of radius $r$.

Comment: You should note first that the law of the Euclidian norm of a multidimensional Brownian Motion is invariant under rotation and second try to determine this law.Best regards

Comment: @TheBridge, could you elaborate? I don't know the law of law of Euclidean norm of a multidimensional Brownian Motion. Do you mean something like use the Stochastic Differential Equation in page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_process?

Comment: Are Ws and Wt wiener processes or just standard normal random variables? The formulas you propose later on in the post (suitably corrected) seem to indicate the latter.

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent standard normal random variables and $R=\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$ then, for every nonnegative $r$,
$$
P(R\leqslant r)=\iint_{x^2+y^2\leqslant r^2}\frac1{2\pi}\mathrm e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}\mathrm dx\mathrm dy.
$$
The change of variable $(x,y)=(s\cos t,s\sin t)$ with $s\geqslant0$ and $t$ in $[0,2\pi)$ is rather ubiquitous in such a gaussian context and yields
$$
P(R\leqslant r)=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^r\frac1{2\pi}\mathrm e^{-s^2/2}s\mathrm ds\mathrm dt=\int_0^rs\mathrm e^{-s^2/2}\mathrm ds=\mathrm e^{-r^2/2},
$$
which shows at the same time that the CDF $F_R$ and the PDF $f_R$ of $R$ are defined on $r\geqslant0$ respectively by
$$
F_R(r)=\mathrm e^{-r^2/2},\qquad f_R(r)=r\mathrm e^{-r^2/2}.
$$
The same reasoning shows that, for every $n\geqslant1$, the random variable $$R_n=\sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2+\cdots+X_n^2},$$ with the analogue conventions, has a density $f_n$ proportional to $g_n$, where
$$
g_n(r)=r^{n-1}\mathrm e^{-r^2/2}.
$$